# rhel7 pxe boot issue with dhcp gets wrong address

Tags: linux, pxe-boot

I am trying to setup a new PXE boot setup and all seems to be okay, but when it tries to get kickstart file, it says network unreachable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLicr.png)

when I am looking at dhcp logs it says it's getting worng network

```
Jan 18 02:39:24 rhel7m dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:0c:29:ae:dd:83 via eno16777736
Jan 18 02:39:25 rhel7m dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.5.10 to 00:0c:29:ae:dd:83 via eno16777736
Jan 18 02:39:26 rhel7m dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.5.10 (192.168.5.111) from 00:0c:29:ae:dd:83 via eno16777736
Jan 18 02:39:26 rhel7m dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.5.10 to 00:0c:29:ae:dd:83 via eno16777736
Jan 18 02:39:26 rhel7m in.tftpd[2912]: tftp: client does not accept options
Jan 18 02:39:35 rhel7m dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:0c:29:ae:dd:83 via eno16777736
Jan 18 02:39:35 rhel7m dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.5.10 to 00:0c:29:ae:dd:83 via eno16777736
Jan 18 02:39:35 rhel7m dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.130.128 (192.168.130.254) from 00:0c:29:ae:dd:83 via eno16777736: wrong network.
Jan 18 02:39:35 rhel7m dhcpd: DHCPNAK on 192.168.130.128 to 00:0c:29:ae:dd:83 via eno16777736
```

---

```
[root@rhel7m ~]# cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
#option domain-name-servers 145.253.2.75, 193.174.32.18;

default-lease-time 86400;
max-lease-time 604800;

authoritative;

subnet 192.168.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 192.168.5.10 192.168.5.49;
        filename "pxelinux.0";
        option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
        option broadcast-address 192.168.5.255;
        option routers 192.168.5.111;
}
```

any thoughts please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one DHCP server providing IP addresses in your environment.

The first DHCP server IP = 192.168.5.111

The second DHCP server IP = 192.168.130.254 (probably a VMware DHCP server)

Remember the first DHCP request is a PXE DHCP request, the second DHCP request (after booting kernel/initrd) is a plain DHCP request

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes, the VMs are hosted VM workstation and I have no clue from where the second DHCP server (192.168.130.254) is from, is any way I can disable it?

Comment: The second DHCP server belongs to VMware Workstation virtual network.
You can turn it off; open Workstation, go to `Edit/Virtual Network Editor` and disable DHCP. Or just quit VMware Workstation if possible.

Comment: wow Pat, ur master, Thanks, Yes, the VM workstation was the sending second DHCP :), disabled it in VM workstation and it works now :)